# Is Kendo UI Core Grid open source?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am trying to create a application which involves in heavy usage of data grid. I found in few articles that telerik kendo ui grid is free to use. As there is lot of confusion on telerik grid as open source from link 2, I am trying to check if someone really used this as open source. Is it really open source and free to use?
[Link 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4ff85/kendo-ui-core-grid/), [Link 2](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open source version of Kendo UI used to include the grid component, but no longer does:

> Now, not all Kendo UI widgets are created equal. Some widgets - like
>   the **Grid**, Scheduler, and Editor - are so feature-rich that they're
>   more solutions than widgets. As such, they consume a great deal of
>   engineering effort to build and maintain. To ensure that critical
>   widgets like these continue to get the proper attention and focus they
>   deserve from our engineering team, **we’ve decided to offer these only
>   with Kendo UI Professional** (formerly Kendo UI Complete)

The original announcement is available here: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/announcing-kendo-ui-core

You can also see a full comparison of the two versions here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison